# Changing Joomla Database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm new with Joomla and I need to know:

- What happen if i change the default joomla installation database for
  anotherone?
- What is stored in that database?
- Could I use my own database according to my needs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
What happen if i change the default joomla installation database for another one?
```

Joomla will be installed to the given database. Nothing else. If you change the database after you installed Joomla It's not gonna work. Joomla has a unique structured database.

```
What is stored in that database?
```

Data which is needed to run Joomla CMS. Also Component, Plugin, Module data will be stored there.

```
Could I use my own database according to my need ?
```

Yes you can do anything you like, to the table you created. It's not a good idea to change the core one's.

why don't you try it yourself and see ? If you have any specific issues let me know. This is too board to explain here.

Read Joomla Documentation and follow few tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your database for another one, your Joomla site will most likely not work as Joomla has a rather specific database structure. The majority of all the data you see on a Joomla site is stored in the database, such as articles, modules positions, extensions, user details, etc etc.

You can use your own database, but seeing as you're new to Joomla, looks at the documentation sites and see how Joomla actually works. A lot of people like to use the Joomla library for their hand written sites and there are lots of tutorials on how to import it.